# javascript code to scan barcode not working with ip address

Tags: javascript, jquery, webcam

`Javascript` code to scan barcode not working with IP address. It is working only with localhost. For example if I use URL: `192.168.1.120:8080/projectname/controller/htmlpage` , the camera doesn't start but if I use URL: `localhost:8080/projectname/controller/htmlpage` camera opens.  I am using MVC Architecture

Following is my code `HTML` Code:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/barcode.js"></script>
<br>
<br>
<div id="message" style="color: green; font: bold; height: 50%"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var sound = new Audio("js/barcode.wav");
    $(document).ready(function() {
        barcode.config.start = 0.1;
        barcode.config.end = 0.9;
        barcode.config.video = '#barcodevideo';
        barcode.config.canvas = '#barcodecanvas';
        barcode.config.canvasg = '#barcodecanvasg';
        barcode.setHandler(function(barcode) {
            $('#result').val(barcode);
            sound.play();
            $.ajax({
                url : "/Factory/staffAttendance/saveAttendaceViaScanner",
                data : {
                    barcode : barcode
                },
                success : function(response) {
                    $('#message').html(response);
                },
                error : function(e) {

                }
            });

        });
        barcode.init();
    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="barcode">
        <video id="barcodevideo" autoplay></video>
        <canvas id="barcodecanvasg"></canvas>
    </div>
    <canvas id="barcodecanvas"></canvas>

    <input type="hidden" id="result" value="" 
        name="barcode">
    <br>
    <br>
```

Following is my js code for barcode scanning and to start web cam:

```
var barcode = function() {

    var localMediaStream = null;
    var bars = [];
    var handler = null;

    var dimensions = {
        height: 0,
        width: 0,
        start: 0,
        end: 0
    }

    var elements = {
        video: null,
        canvas: null,
        ctx: null,  
        canvasg: null,
        ctxg: null  
    }

    var upc = {
        '0': [3, 2, 1, 1],
        '1': [2, 2, 2, 1],
        '2': [2, 1, 2, 2],
        '3': [1, 4, 1, 1],
        '4': [1, 1, 3, 2],
        '5': [1, 2, 3, 1],
        '6': [1, 1, 1, 4],
        '7': [1, 3, 1, 2],
        '8': [1, 2, 1, 3],
        '9': [3, 1, 1, 2]
    };

    var check = {
        'oooooo': '0',
        'ooeoee': '1',
        'ooeeoe': '2',
        'ooeeeo': '3',
        'oeooee': '4',
        'oeeooe': '5',
        'oeeeoo': '6',
        'oeoeoe': '7',
        'oeoeeo': '8',
        'oeeoeo': '9'
    }

    var config = {
        strokeColor: '#f00',
        start: 0.1,
        end: 0.9,
        threshold: 160,
        quality: 0.45,
        delay: 6000,
        video: '',
        canvas: '',
        canvasg: ''
    }

    function init() {

        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
        elements.video = document.querySelector(config.video);
        elements.canvas = document.querySelector(config.canvas);
        elements.ctx = elements.canvas.getContext('2d');
        elements.canvasg = document.querySelector(config.canvasg);
        elements.ctxg = elements.canvasg.getContext('2d');

        if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
                alert(stream)
                elements.video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
            }, function(error) {
                alert(error)
                console.log(error);
            });
        }

        elements.video.addEventListener('canplay', function(e) {

            dimensions.height = elements.video.videoHeight;
            dimensions.width = elements.video.videoWidth;

            dimensions.start = dimensions.width * config.start;
            dimensions.end = dimensions.width * config.end;

            elements.canvas.width = dimensions.width;
            elements.canvas.height = dimensions.height;
            elements.canvasg.width = dimensions.width;
            elements.canvasg.height = dimensions.height;

            drawGraphics();
            setInterval(function(){snapshot()}, config.delay);

        }, false);
    }

    function snapshot() {
        elements.ctx.drawImage(elements.video, 0, 0, dimensions.width, dimensions.height);
        processImage();     
    }

    function processImage() {

        bars = [];

        var pixels = [];
        var binary = [];
        var pixelBars = [];

        // convert to grayscale

        var imgd = elements.ctx.getImageData(dimensions.start, dimensions.height * 0.5, dimensions.end - dimensions.start, 1);
        var rgbpixels = imgd.data;

        for (var i = 0, ii = rgbpixels.length; i < ii; i = i + 4) {
            pixels.push(Math.round(rgbpixels[i] * 0.2126 + rgbpixels[i + 1] * 0.7152 + rgbpixels[ i + 2] * 0.0722));
        }

        // normalize and convert to binary

        var min = Math.min.apply(null, pixels);
        var max = Math.max.apply(null, pixels);

        for (var i = 0, ii = pixels.length; i < ii; i++) {
            if (Math.round((pixels[i] - min) / (max - min) * 255) > config.threshold) {             
                binary.push(1);
            } else {
                binary.push(0);
            }
        }

        // determine bar widths

        var current = binary[0];
        var count = 0;

        for (var i = 0, ii = binary.length; i < ii; i++) {
            if (binary[i] == current) {
                count++;
            } else {
                pixelBars.push(count);
                count = 1;
                current = binary[i]
            }
        }
        pixelBars.push(count);

        // quality check

        if (pixelBars.length < (3 + 24 + 5 + 24 + 3 + 1)) {
            return;
        }

        // find starting sequence

        var startIndex = 0;
        var minFactor = 0.5;
        var maxFactor = 1.5;

        for (var i = 3, ii = pixelBars.length; i < ii; i++) {
            var refLength = (pixelBars[i] + pixelBars[i-1] + pixelBars[i-2]) / 3;
            if (
                (pixelBars[i] > (minFactor * refLength) || pixelBars[i] < (maxFactor * refLength))
                && (pixelBars[i-1] > (minFactor * refLength) || pixelBars[i-1] < (maxFactor * refLength))
                && (pixelBars[i-2] > (minFactor * refLength) || pixelBars[i-2] < (maxFactor * refLength))
                && (pixelBars[i-3] > 3 * refLength)
            ) {
                startIndex = i - 2;
                break;
            }
        }

        console.log("startIndex: " + startIndex );

        // return if no starting sequence found

        if (startIndex == 0) {
            return;
        }

        // discard leading and trailing patterns

        pixelBars = pixelBars.slice(startIndex, startIndex + 3 + 24 + 5 + 24 + 3);

        console.log("pixelBars: " + pixelBars );

        // calculate relative widths

        var ref = (pixelBars[0] + pixelBars[1] + pixelBars[2]) / 3;

        for (var i = 0, ii = pixelBars.length; i < ii; i++) {
            bars.push(Math.round(pixelBars[i] / ref * 100) / 100);
        }

        // analyze pattern

        analyze();

    }   

    function analyze() {

        console.clear();

        console.log("analyzing");

        // determine parity first digit and reverse sequence if necessary

        var first = normalize(bars.slice(3, 3 + 4), 7);
        if (!isOdd(Math.round(first[1] + first[3]))) {
            bars = bars.reverse();
        }

        // split into digits

        var digits = [
            normalize(bars.slice(3, 3 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(7, 7 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(11, 11 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(15, 15 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(19, 19 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(23, 23 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(32, 32 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(36, 36 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(40, 40 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(44, 44 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(48, 48 + 4), 7),
            normalize(bars.slice(52, 52 + 4), 7)
        ]

        console.log("digits: " + digits);

        // determine parity and reverse if necessary

        var parities = [];

        for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
            if (parity(digits[i])) {
                parities.push('o');
            } else {
                parities.push('e');
                digits[i] = digits[i].reverse();
            }
        }       

        // identify digits

        var result = [];    
        var quality = 0;

        for (var i = 0, ii = digits.length; i < ii; i++) {

            var distance = 9;
            var bestKey = '';

            for (key in upc) {
                if (maxDistance(digits[i], upc[key]) < distance) {
                    distance = maxDistance(digits[i], upc[key]);
                    bestKey = key;
                }   
            }

            result.push(bestKey);
            if (distance > quality) {
                quality = distance;
            }

        }

        console.log("result: " + result);   

        // check digit

        var checkDigit = check[parities.join('')];

        // output

        console.log("quality: " + quality);

        if(quality < config.quality) {
            if (handler != null) {
                handler(checkDigit + result.join(''));
            }
        }

    }

    function setHandler(h) {
        handler = h;
    }

    function normalize(input, total) {
        var sum = 0;
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0, ii = input.length; i < ii; i++) {
            sum = sum + input[i];
        }
        for (var i = 0, ii = input.length; i < ii; i++) {
            result.push(input[i] / sum * total);
        }
        return result;
    }

    function isOdd(num) { 
        return num % 2;
    }

    function maxDistance(a, b) {
        var distance = 0;
        for (var i = 0, ii = a.length; i < ii; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(a[i] - b[i]) > distance) {
                distance = Math.abs(a[i] - b[i]);
            }
        }
        return distance;
    }

    function parity(digit) {
        return isOdd(Math.round(digit[1] + digit[3]));
    }

    function drawGraphics() {
        elements.ctxg.strokeStyle = config.strokeColor;
        elements.ctxg.lineWidth = 3;
        elements.ctxg.beginPath();
        elements.ctxg.moveTo(dimensions.start, dimensions.height * 0.5);
        elements.ctxg.lineTo(dimensions.end, dimensions.height * 0.5);
        elements.ctxg.stroke();
    }

    return {
        init: init,
        setHandler: setHandler,
        config: config
    };

    // debugging utilities

    function drawBars(binary) {
        for (var i = 0, ii = binary.length; i < ii; i++) {
            if (binary[i] == 1) {
                elements.ctxg.strokeStyle = '#fff';
            } else {
                elements.ctxg.strokeStyle = '#000';
            }
            elements.ctxg.lineWidth = 3;
            elements.ctxg.beginPath();
            elements.ctxg.moveTo(start + i, height * 0.5);
            elements.ctxg.lineTo(start + i + 1, height * 0.5);
            elements.ctxg.stroke();
        }
    }

}();
```

You can see the image with application running on localhost where camera has started:

[image]

You can see the image with application running on ip address where camera has not started:

[image]

Comment: what is the response of your http request when you try with the IP 192.... ? Could by a cross over domain issue.

Comment: Hello @StéphaneAmmar error says [object navigatorusermediaerror]

Comment: After or before your server response ? is your response status is 200 ?

Comment: before response and my js execution breaks after  [object navigatorusermediaerror] .

Comment: With ip address alert is showing and with localhost alert is not showing.
  if (navigator.getUserMedia) {
   navigator.webkitGetUserMedia({audio: true, video: true}, function(stream) {
   
    elements.video.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
   }, function(error) {
    alert("error "+error)
    console.log(error);
   });
  }

Comment: did you put 'http://' in your url, before ip adress ?

Comment: it automatically considers http:// @StéphaneAmmar and i also tried specifically providing http:// still it doesnt work

Comment: I hope question is clear to you @StéphaneAmmar

Comment: Is there any chance you have both windows open at the same time?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793599/why-is-getusermedia-throwing-a-object-navigatorusermediaerror-when-i-click-al#23339597

Comment: I have solved my issue, to access getUserMedia we need to have https 
(i mean we must have secure origins)

Answer (score 0):

Check below link:
Instead of getUserMedia() use MediaRecorder().

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=571124

Comment: Where exactly you are asking me to change? @Sadhu